# PHP - Why isn't this fatal error being caught?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

```
function truExceptionHandler($no, $str, $file, $line) {
    if ($str != "Only variables should be assigned by reference") {
        echo '<br/><pre>';
        echo "<b>[ERROR] ".$str." in ".$file." on line ".$line."</b><br/>";
        print_r(debug_backtrace(2));
    }
}

set_error_handler('truExceptionHandler');
```

My above function isn't catching the error `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\site.com\system\core\Common.php on line 328`

What do I need to change to be sure it's caught?

Answer (score 3):

A fatal error is fatal. You can't catch it, PHP is now [DOA](http://www.google.com.au/url?ei=xrrATaXNCYiGrAezm_DWAw&sig2=viLQhqH4u6lhkX7mGp-LSw&q=http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/DOA&sa=X&ved=0CBYQpAMoBw&usg=AFQjCNGyhW1ZvwYT_7r2LjlPWRk6jhaazA). In particular, that error is a stack overflow. It makes little sense in the context of a stack overflow to expect PHP to create a new stack frame to call your error handler.

Comment: Then how can I determine the cause of this error?  How can I figure out what functions are looping?

Comment: @Webnet: Code inspection, or perhaps something like `xdebug` may be useful too. On an unrelated note, this is one of my pet peeves in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you cannot catch a fatal error. That's why they are called fatal errors. But, if you really want to, there's a dirty little hack that you can use. Use `register_shutdown_function`. Shutdown functions are still called after a FATAL_ERROR has occured. E.g:

```
function onShutdown()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    if (null !== $error && E_ERROR === $error['type']) {
        // A FATAL_ERROR occured
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('onShutdown');
```

Let me repeat to drive the point home: **This is a dirty hack (but it works)!**

Comment: His exact error `Maximum function nesting level` doesn't trigger shutdown functions (anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a recursion error. It basically means you have 100 function calls on the stack i.e. if function a1 calls function a2 which calls function a3 ....... calls function a100.